# XML standards: Namespaces defined at root level

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces, xsd-validation

Can all namespaces be defined at the root element according to xml best practice? Please see simplified example below:

```xml
<ns1:Root xmlns:ns1="Root" xmlns:ns2="urn...." xmlns:ns3="urn...">
  <ns1:Tag1></ns1:Tag1>
  <ns2:Tag2></ns2:Tag2>
  <ns3:Tag3></ns3:Tag3>
</ns1:Root>
```

Question more about standards and best practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, and it's sometimes useful, but it should never be necessary. For example if you have a SOAP structure with an application payload inside a SOAP envelope, it's perfectly acceptable to declare the application namespaces at the "payload" level.

"Best practice" is whatever makes your life easier, and that depends on what you're doing with the XML.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the XML standard allows that all XML namespace prefixes can be defined at the root level.

Yes, many recommend defining XML namespace prefixes only at the root level as a best practice.

No, one should not assume, or write code that assumes, that XML namespace prefixes will only be defined at the root level.